# Trying to save data to firebase realtime store using the Admin SDK but whenever I close the connection, the data doesn't save

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm able to save information to the database when I'm not closing the database afterwards, however then the program hangs and doesn't finish. It only finishes when I call something similar to "`db.goOffline`".

```
import * as cert from './ebay-prices-admin.js';

export function getDB () {
  const serviceAccount = cert['default'];

  admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "removed"
  });
  
  var db = admin.database();
  return db;
}

export async function addCoin(db, search, coins){
  try {
    var ref = db.ref(search);
      for (let i = 0; i < coins.length; i++){
        const coinRef = ref.child(revisedRandId()); 
        coinRef.set({
          name: coins[i].name,
          price: coins[i].price,
          shipping: coins[i].shipping,
          date: coins[i].date,
        })
        coinRef.off();
      };
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
    return () => db.ref(search).off('value');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to store the array `coins` into your database under the path `search`, you would use:

```
export async function addCoin(db, search, coins) {
  // compile a key-value map of new data to be written
  const pendingUpdates = coins.reduce(
    (acc, coinInfo) => {
      acc[revisedRandId()] = {
        name: coinInfo.name,
        price: coinInfo.price,
        shipping: coinInfo.shipping,
        date: coinInfo.date,
      };
      return acc;
    },
    {}
  );

  // apply changes to database
  return db.ref(search)
    .update(pendingUpdates);
}
```

Then to use it:

```
try {
  await addCoin(db, "path/in/db", [ { name: "ABC", price: 123, shipping: 0, date: new Date() } ]);
  console.log("database updated")
} catch (err) {
  console.error("Failed to update database", err);
}
```

or

```
addCoin(db, "path/in/db", [ { name: "ABC", price: 123, shipping: 0, date: new Date() } ])
  .then(() => console.log("database updated"))
  .catch((err) => console.error("Failed to update database", err));
```

Comment: Thank you but I get the error "Failed to update database TypeError: obj.hasOwnProperty is not a function"

Comment: `Object.create(null)` <- Firebase doesn't like these, just use a plain, empty object `{}`

Comment: @Phil thank you that worked. The program still seems to hang however after displaying "database updated", I have to Ctrl+C to get out

Comment: @dede That's entirely dependent on how you are using this code. It seems that whatever you are using to run this code is not terminating when it detects asynchronous code (as it should). If you want the program to quit when it's done as if you were writing some CLI tool, you need to call `process.exit()` after logging that the database updated.

Comment: @samthecodingman I'm even more confused now because the program doesn't hang when I use an emulated database